# Regex match that may or may not be there

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm filtering access lists from a router.  I want to identify the sequence number (i.e., 10,20,30,40) and the permit/deny statements and also want to identify how many hits (matches) there are.  In some cases there aren't any hits so that will be blank.  In my example below the regex doesn't match the last line because there is no (xxx matches) on that line.  I want a single regex that will also match the lines that don't have (xxx matches).

[Regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/YPLmnM/2)

[image: regex101]

Comment: So you want to match all those lines? What should have a line to be matchable by the regex? What text do you want to capture also in a matched line?

Comment: What's your question exactly? It sounds like you want to use one regex if the input contains "matches", otherwise use another regex -- is that right? Please [edit] the question. It would also help a lot to add different possible input and expected output. See [mre] for reference, and [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: Sorry, not a well worded questions.  I just updated it.  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex to collect all the relevant fields

```
r"(\d+)\s+(\S+).+?([0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3}){3})\s+(?:\((\d+) matches\))?"
```

**Details:**

- `(\d+)` : capture group - 1+ digits
- `\s+` : follow by 1+ whitespaces
- `(\S+)` : capture group - any non-whitespace character
- `.+?` : follow by 1+ any character, non-greedy (except line ending)
- `([0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3}){3})` : capture group - poor man's IP capture
- `\s+` : follow by 1+ whitespaces
- `(?:` : (an optional) non-capturing group

  - `\((\d+) matches\)` : capture group - 1+ digits, surround by literals
- `)?` : optional group

Input used as **file.txt**

```
    10 permit 10.8.1.26 (1284 matches)
    20 permit 10.8.2.200 (22 matches)
    30 permit 10.8.3.200 (160 matches)
    40 permit ip host 10.8.1.26 any
    50 deny ip host 10.8.1.26 any
    60 deny ip host 10.8.111.126 (14 matches)
    70 permit 127.15.200.211 (5622 matches)
    80 permit 101.18.211.121 (1 matches)
    90 deny ip host 10.8.1.26 any
```

```
import re

regex = r"(\d+)\s+(\S+).+?([0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3}){3})\s+(?:\((\d+) matches\))?"

with open("file.txt") as f:
    data = f.readlines()

for line in data:
    match = re.findall(regex, line)
    if match:
        print(match)
```

```
[('10', 'permit', '10.8.1.26', '1284')]
[('20', 'permit', '10.8.2.200', '22')]
[('30', 'permit', '10.8.3.200', '160')]
[('40', 'permit', '10.8.1.26', '')]
[('50', 'deny', '10.8.1.26', '')]
[('60', 'deny', '10.8.111.126', '14')]
[('70', 'permit', '127.15.200.211', '5622')]
[('80', 'permit', '101.18.211.121', '1')]
[('90', 'deny', '10.8.1.26', '')]
```